# How do I enable BSON serialization in my ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, bson

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and network programming in general. I've just successfully completed my first ASP.NET Core Web API based on RESTfull design principles. It's currently using JSON serialization to send out the responses (the Visual Studio default) but I'd like to try BSON. I've spent the day googling and I can't seem to find any examples of how to add BSON serialization/deserialization capability to the server. I've come across several articles on how to do this on full-framework ASP.NET, where it's been included out-of-the-box for several years (for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21 and http://www.strathweb.com/2012/07/bson-binary-json-and-how-your-web-api-can-be-even-faster/) but nothing pertaining to ASP.NET Core specifically.

I've hunted through the source code files generated by VS hoping to find something similar to the full-framework examples I've linked but nothing jumped out at me as there were few similarities. Could someone please post (or link to) some code that shows how this is done in ASP.NET Core? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this formatter: https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib.Core

Then add at startup.cs:

```
using WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Bson;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddBsonSerializerFormatters();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that. However, I'm surprised to see yet another modular package install required for this. Doesn't ASP.NET Core support BSON serialization out-of-box? Or is this the "official" BSON support for .NET Core?

Comment: A BinaryFormatter support will be on .net core 2.0:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/10144

Comment: @FabriDamazio 2.0 is out, so now how can a `BinaryFormatter` enable BSON?

Comment: @HappyNomad maybe you can find something here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization

Comment: @FabriDamazio Thanks, looks interesting.  But in my case at least, binary serialization isn't an alternative to BSON.

Comment: @LKeene The WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Bson library has little code and is rarely maintained, so there's no real need to reference it via Nuget.  Consider instead to just include the formatters in your project.  Whereas the library uses Json.NET's serializer, I need that of MongoDB.  So I just used it as an example while [rolling my own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-formatters) `OutputFormatter`.

Comment: I think you going to use `AddControllers().AddBsonSerializerFormatters()` for a web api project in net core